# why is cron flooding wtmp and last?

Tags: linux, cron, last

When I type the last command, I see a bunch of entries in there for cron. Every single cron job that gets run creates an entry and it's flooding wtmp with unnecessary entries. Any ideas how I can stop cron from doing that? The entries look like the following:

`root     cron                          Sat Feb 06 12:50 - 12:50  (00:00)
root     cron                          Sat Feb 06 12:40 - 12:40  (00:00)
root     cron                          Sat Feb 06 12:30 - 12:30  (00:00)
myuser   pts/0        :0.0             Sat Feb 06 10:30 - 12:30  (02:00)`

Comment: Check your system clock. It appears you have it set to the wrong _year_.

Comment: thanks, but no, that's not it. i had to type it in manually because these servers are on an isolated network. i just copied and pasted the same line with a typo over and over

Comment: check your cronjobs. a cronjob might spawn a login-shell to execute a command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely done by your pam configuration. Check either `/etc/pam.conf` or the files in `/etc/pam.d/*` for lines containing `pam_lastlog.so`. From the `pam_lastlog(8)` manual:

> DESCRIPTION
>          pam_lastlog is a PAM module to display a line of information about the last login of the user. **In addition, the module maintains the /var/log/lastlog file**.

The exact solution depends on your overall pam configuration. You can either tell `pam_lastlog` no not write to `/var/log/wtmp` or you can skip pam_lastlog only for cron sessions.